# How to create a new key-value pair in a dictionary in a cell in Pandas DataFrame based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to add a new key-value pair to the pandas dataframe column based on the condition. Destination column data is in dictionary format. So if the conditon is true, it is necessary to create pair otherwise, no action is needed. I am trying to make it through np.where:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"amenity": ["1","2","3","4"], "tags": [{"building":"yes"},{"entrance": "yes"},{},{}], "sport": [None, "hockey", "football", None], "leisure":["multi", "some", "field", "wake"]})

leisure_var_add = ["field", "multi"]

df['tags']['sport'] = np.where((df['sport'] != None) | (df['leisure'].isin(leisure_var_add))), df['sport'], None)
df['tags']['leisure'] = np.where((df['sport'] == None) & (df['leisure'] !=None) & (~df['leisure'].isin(leisure_var_add)), df['leisure'], None)
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
  amenity                                         tags     sport leisure
0       1          {'building':'yes','sport': 'multi'}      None   multi
1       2        {'entrance': 'yes','sport': 'hockey'}    hokkey    some
2       3    {'sport': 'football', 'leisure': 'field'}  football   field
3       4                          {'leisure': 'wake'}      None    wake
```

I have implemented this task with a loop over each row and operations with indexes, but in this case, I lose all benefits of Pandas. Do you have any idea how it can be implemented?

Comment: The cell dict have to be updated individually.  There's no way with `pandas` or `numpy` to operate on a whole Series of dict at once.  `tags` Series dtype is `object`

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension:

```
df['tags'] = df[['sport', 'leisure']] \
                 .apply(lambda x: {k: v for k, v in x[x.notna()].items()}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  amenity                                       tags     sport leisure
0       1                       {'leisure': 'multi'}      None   multi
1       2     {'sport': 'hokkey', 'leisure': 'some'}    hokkey    some
2       3  {'sport': 'football', 'leisure': 'field'}  football   field
3       4                        {'leisure': 'wake'}      None    wake
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I would like to use conditions, in my case I also need to refer to list of values - leisure_var_add.  So in row 1 there should not be 'leisure': 'some'. In addition in some 'tags' dictionaries could be other values and I cannot rewrite the dictionary.

Comment: With `apply` this is still iteration over each row, regardless of whether it makes a new `dict` or modifies the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

i moved all the data to columns using an apply then iterrate the rows building a dictionary of tags using the column data excluding amenity

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"amenity": ["1","2","3","4"], "tags": [{"building":"yes"},{"entrance": "yes"},{},{}], "sport": [None, "hockey", "football", None], "leisure":["multi", "some", "field", "wake"]})

def EmptyList(x):
    if len(x)>0:
        return x[0]
    else:
        return None

 df['building']=df['tags'].apply(lambda x: [v for k,v in x.items() if k=='building']).apply(EmptyList)
 df['entrance']=df['tags'].apply(lambda x: [v for k,v in x.items() if k=='entrance']).apply(EmptyList)
 df.drop(['tags'],inplace=True,axis=1)
 print(df)

 tags_dict={}
 columns=df.columns
 for key,value in df.iterrows():
    for column in columns:
        if value[column]!=None and column != 'amenity':
            #print(value[column])
            tags_dict[column]=value[column]
     #print(tags_dict)
     df.loc[key,'tags']=str(tags_dict)
     tags_dict.clear()

 print(df)
```

output

```
  amenity     sport leisure building entrance  \
0       1      None   multi      yes     None   
1       2    hockey    some     None      yes   
2       3  football   field     None     None   
3       4      None    wake     None     None   

                                            tags  
0            {'leisure': 'multi', 'building': 'yes'}  
1  {'sport': 'hockey', 'leisure': 'some', 'entran...  
2          {'sport': 'football', 'leisure': 'field'}  
3                                {'leisure': 'wake'}
```